# Border bottom center with fade out

Tags: css, border

How do i create border that is centered with a fade out effect towards the edges of the element
Example below: (The bottom border)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use background effect on container box:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#777), to(#fff));
```